# Optaplanner Best Score Null Pointer exception

Tags: optaplanner

```
14:46:27.239 [main] INFO  o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving started: time spent (155), best score (3uninitialized/-3hard/-3soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
14:46:27.320 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (0), time spent (237), score (0hard/-2soft), selected move count (3), picked move (Requests [id=4, res=null] {null -> Resources [Name=Doc2, Id=0002]}).
14:46:27.331 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (1), time spent (248), score (3hard/-1soft), selected move count (3), picked move (Requests [id=5, res=null] {null -> Resources [Name=Doc2, Id=0002]}).
14:46:27.347 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (2), time spent (264), score (5hard/0soft), selected move count (3), picked move (Requests [id=6, res=null] {null -> Resources [Name=Doc2, Id=0002]}).
14:46:27.348 [main] INFO  o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase - Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (3), time spent (264), best score (null).
```

Although the score is calculated in step 1 and 2 why i am getting Null Pointer Exception for Best Score.

ERROR MSG

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScore.compareTo(HardSoftScore.java:152)
at org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScore.compareTo(HardSoftScore.java:30)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.acceptor.lateacceptance.LateAcceptanceAcceptor.isAccepted(LateAcceptanceAcceptor.java:67)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.processMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:166)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.doMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:149)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(LocalSearchDecider.java:121)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:72)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runPhases(DefaultSolver.java:215)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:176)
at app.resourceAllocation.main(resourceAllocation.java:44)
```

Comment: What version of OptaPlanner is this? I've never seen this. It's impossible in theory, so you must have something special. If it reproduces on 6.5.0.Final or better yet 7.0.0.Beta3+, can you [create a jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER) with an isolated reproducer?

Comment: its 6.5.0.Final

Comment: forgot to change the overridden method setscore.  Thanks for help. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-207 some years ago.